# How to replace strings in a list by numbers based on their endings?

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, replace

Assume I have a list like this

```
myList = ['A_x1', 'B_x2', 'C_x1', 'D_x3', 'E_x1']
```

and a dictionary like this

```
myDict = {'_x1': 0.1, '_x2': 0.5, '_x3': 0.7}
```

Now I would like to replace all strings in `myList` by the value stored in  `myDict` associated to the ending of this string. I can of course achieve that by using the following:

```
for ind, l in enumerate(myList):
    for k in myDict.iterkeys():
        if l.endswith(k):
            myList[ind] = myDict[k]
```

which gives me the desired output:

```
[0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.7, 0.1].
```

But how could this be done using e.g. `map` or anything else more efficient?

Comment: is it always last 3 characters?

Comment: @AnandSKumar: No, endings can have different lengths.

Comment: Do you always exclude only the first character?

Comment: @Cleb would it always start with `_` ?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: No, you could also have 'WE_someending' as a string.

Comment: Is the key in `myDict` always from the first underscore in the list element?

Comment: @AnandSKumar: Usually, the ending starts with an underscore, yes, so I would definitely accept an answer that does the job. But if you can come up with a general version, I would highly appreciate that, too, of course.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Yes, usually the key starts with underscore; so I would accept an answer that solves this problem. But if you can come up with a general version, I would highly appreciate that, too, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i, e in enumerate(myList):
    key = e[e.index("_"):]
    if key not in myDict: continue
    myList[i] = myDict[key]
```

Comment: Thanks, that works fine. So I upvote it and might accept it depending on the quality of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

If all the dictionary keys are always starting with `_` (underscore) , you can use `str.rsplit` and list comprehension -

```
myList[:] = [myDict.get('_' + elem.rsplit('_',1)[1],elem) for elem in myList]
```

Demo -

```
>>> myList = ['A_x1', 'B_x2', 'C_x1', 'D_x3', 'E_x1']
>>> myDict = {'_x1': 0.1, '_x2': 0.5, '_x3': 0.7}
>>> myList[:] = [myDict.get('_' + elem.rsplit('_',1)[1],elem) for elem in myList]
>>> myList
[0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.7, 0.1]
```

---

For a general version (basically your nested loop in a list comprehension done using `next()`) . Example -

```
myList[:] = [myDict.get(next((key for key in myDict if elem.endswith(key)),None),elem) 
             for elem in myList]
```

Demo -

```
>>> myList = ['A_x1', 'B_x2', 'C_x1', 'D_x3', 'E_x1']
>>> myDict = {'_x1': 0.1, '_x2': 0.5, '_x3': 0.7}
>>>
>>> myList[:] = [myDict.get(next((key for key in myDict if elem.endswith(key)),None),elem)
...              for elem in myList]
>>>
>>> myList
[0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.7, 0.1]
```

But I would prefer the nested for loop (even though it maybe a bit slower) for readability.

Comment: Thanks, that works fine. So I upvote it and might accept it depending on the quality of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your real data looks, the following could be used:

```
myList = ['A_x1', 'B_x2', 'C_x1', 'D_x3', 'E_x1']
myDict = {'_x1': 0.1, '_x2': 0.5, '_x3': 0.7}

print [myDict[x[-3:]] for x in myList]
```

Giving:

```
[0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.7, 0.1]
```

Comment: Thanks, that works fine if my keys are always of length 3 (what my question implies). So I upvote it and might accept it depending on the quality of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
# first map through lambda gets the endings.
# second map applies the endings as keys to myDict

print(list(map(myDict.get,map(lambda x: x[-3:],myList))))

[0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.7, 0.1]
```

Comment: Thanks, that works fine if my keys are always of length 3 (what my question implies). So I upvote it and might accept it depending on the quality of the other answers.

Comment: @Cleb if the keys are always of length 3, map is not a bad choice since it is faster then list comprehensions.